# How to efficiently populate a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I need to populate a matrix $A_{kl}$, where

$$ k = (m-1)J+n$$
$$ l = (p-1)J+q$$

And

$$m,p = 1, 2, ..., I$$
$$n,q = 1, 2, ..., J$$

Its components are `(mnpq)`. For populate it, I'm using an expensive 4 `Do` loop

```
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   Do[
    Print[m, n, p, q];
    k = (m - 1) nC + n;
    l = (p - 1) nC + q;
    If[k <= l, A[[k, l]] = cf[Nfunc, xi, yi, wix, wiy, m, n, p, q], 
     0];
    , {q, 1, J, 1}]
   , {p, 1, I, 1}]
  , {n, 1, J, 1}]
 , {m, 1, I, 1}]
```

Knowing that $A_{kl}$ for a $I=J=2$, its components are `(mnpq)`

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
(1111) & (1112) & (1121) & (1122)\\
   & (1212) & (1221) & (1222)\\
 symm. &        & (2121) & (2122)\\
   &        &        & (2222)\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Does anyone know a more efficient way to populate it? Maybe using a bult-in function?

**UPDATE**

```
cf = Compile[{{Nfunc, _Real, 2}, {xi, _Real, 1}, {yi, _Real, 
     1}, {wix, _Real, 1}, {wiy, _Real, 
     1}, {m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {q, _Integer}},
   Module[{sum},
    sum = 0.0;
    For[i = 1, i <= Length@xi, i++,
     For[j = 1, j <= Length@yi, j++,
      sum = 
        sum + (8 \[Pi]^2)/
           a^2 m p Cos[(m \[Pi] xi[[i]])/((1/
                2) a)] Sin[(n \[Pi] yi[[j]])/((1/
                2) b)] Cos[(p \[Pi] xi[[i]])/((1/
                2) a)] Sin[(q \[Pi] yi[[j]])/((1/2) b)]*wix[[i]]*
          wiy[[j]]*Nfunc[[i, j]];
      ]
     ];
    sum],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Comment: At least you can just use only one `Do`.

Comment: What is the nature of `cf`? Is it `Listable` in any of its arguments? I.e. would `cf[nFunc, xi, yi, wix, wiy, m, n, p, {q1, q2, q3}]` correctly give a list of three values?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, that is the exact point. I'm not getting create a algorithm to only one `Do`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, `m,n,p,q` are integers. All others are lists.

`cf = Compile[{{Nfunc, _Real, 2}, {xi, _Real, 1}, {yi, _Real, 
    1}, {wix, _Real, 1}, {wiy, _Real, 
    1}, {m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {q, _Integer}}.`

Comment: Yes, but you want to evaluate this function not for only **one** value of these integers, but for many different ones. If we put these many different ones in a list, and feed that list to `cf`, will it work? For instance, if I want to find `Sin[x]` for x = 1, 2, 3, ..., 100 I don't need to loop, I just do `Sin[Range[100]]`. I'm asking whether this applies to your function `cf`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I got it now. My `cf` does not calculate for a list of `m`, `n`, `p` and `q`. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $m-1, n-1$ and $p-1, q-1$ are the two digits of $k-1$ and $l-1$, respectively, in base $J$. This should be pretty fast:

```
dim = i*j;
A = ConstantArray[0, {dim, dim}];
Do[
   A[[k, l]] = A[[l, k]] = cf[Nfunc, xi, yi, wix, wiy, Quotient[k - 1, j] + 1, Mod[k - 1, j] + 1, Quotient[l - 1, j] + 1, Mod[l - 1, j]+ 1]
, {k, 1, dim}, {l, k, dim}
]
```

If $IJ$ is huge and your `cf` is very very fast, then you can probably shave off a little bit more time by making an outer `Do` over `k` where you compute the quotient and mod once for that `k`, followed by an inner `Do` over `l`.

Comment: I will update my question adding `cf`. Could you analyse it? Thank you for answering!

Comment: It doing `i = 2; j = 2;
dim = i*j;
A = ConstantArray[0, {dim, dim}];
Do[A[[k, l]] = 
  A[[l, k]] = {Quotient[k, j] + 1, Mod[k, j], Quotient[l, j] + 1, 
    Mod[l, j]}, {k, 1, dim}, {l, k, dim}]`, we do not get the @bill s answer, as should be.

Comment: I have fixed the off-by-one issue.

Comment: Perfect, @Marius. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

One way to create your data structure is to realize that your list of integers is closely related to all the Tuples taken in groups. For the case I=J=2, the permutations are of 1 and 2 taken 4 at a time:

```
mat = Partition[Tuples[{1, 2}, 4], 4];
mask = UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {4, 4}]];
outMat = mat mask + Transpose[mat mask] - mat IdentityMatrix[4]

outMat//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you answering. But I did not understand how I will access each component of the matrix A using your approach.

Comment: Use Part ([[ ]]). For example, outMat[[2, 3]] will give you the 2,3 element of the matrix.

Comment: What a dumb! Sorry for this dumb question! Thank you very much! I accepted the @Marius's answer because it was more straight for me. But, without doubt, your approach is really great too!

Comment: I should also note that generating tuples from a length-$k$ list is isomorphic to getting base-$k$ digits, so: `mat = Partition[IntegerDigits[Range[0, 15], 2, 4] + 1, 4]`